# jQuery pass table row value to ajax post request

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-post

I'm trying to send a value of a table cell to a jQuery POST script.
The `$.ajax` part works when just hard coding the values. Guess I'm doing something wrong with assigning the "extension" variable in jQuery.

Below the jQuery script:

```
<script>                            
function myCall() {
    $(".btn btn-warning btn-sm").click(function () {
      var extension = $(this).closest("tr").find(".Extension").text();
    }

$.ajax("/cura/pages/test.php/",{
type: "GET",
data:{
    action:'pause',
    pauselocation: $extension,
    queue: 'testq',
    paused: 'true'
}           
});

request.done(function(msg) {
    $("#mybox").html(msg);          
});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You're passing the text as an object. Remove the $?

Comment: Not sure I understood it correctly, removed the $, like `pauselocation: extension` But, still doesn't work.

Comment: I'm trying to assign the value to $ extension by this piece of code: `$(".btn btn-warning btn-sm").click(function () {
      var extension = $(this).closest("tr").find(".Extension").text();
    }`

Comment: @Jompie of course it will not work even without `$`. `extension` is **local** click event handler variable, and its value is assigned on `.btn btn-warning btn-sm` click somewhen in future, when ajax request will have already been done.

Comment: @Jompie It looks for me that you have serious **logic** error in your code. `$(".btn btn-warning btn-sm").click(function () { ... }` is click event handler (with missed `);` after `}`, by the way), which will be executed in future on element's click.

Comment: I'm new to js, not sure then where to assign the variable. Should I remove this part: `.click(function ()` ?

Comment: @Jompie there already is answer by JoakinM, but what I want to add is that you should learn how something works **before** using it in your code. Seriously.

Comment: @Regent Removed my comment in frustration since the SO have no clue what so ever what and why things are happening.

Comment: @JoakimM oops, sorry, this comment was for Jompie

Comment: @Jompie You also has undefined variable `request`. Do you understand why it is undefined and what for it is?

Comment: You're right, should have removed that. My starting point was tutorial here: http://www.keyboardninja.eu/webdevelopment/jquery-ajax-call-tutorial

Comment: @Jompie well, if you need something to be done on ajax success/fail, then `request` should stay there. Adding `var request = $.ajax({` is what my question was about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
   $(".btn btn-warning btn-sm").click(function () {
      var extension = $(this).closest("tr").find(".Extension").text();

     $.ajax("/cura/pages/test.php/",{
        type: "GET",
        data:{
        action:'pause',
        pauselocation: extension,
        queue: 'testq',
        paused: 'true'
     });
   });
```

Comment: Well, this is how it is supposed to be, +1.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I still have this at the start: `<script>                            
function myCall() {` The function is called from a button, like: `button onclick="myCall()"' That's correct, right?